# Dynamically proxying of several pages in NuxtJS

Tags: proxy, nuxt.js

In my NuxtJS application I has a folder with html pages, that can be added/deleted in any time from outside (/static/pages/page1.html, /static/pages/page2.html, ...) and I got a mapping to real uri's for this pages

```
{ '/foo': 'page1.html', '/bar': 'page2.html', ... }
```

I know I can use [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy), but it requires to rebuild an app every time mapping changes. I also know I can use nginx's rewrites for this, but changing it's config every time is painful too.

I also tried using 'pages/_.vue' file, read .html in component and place it's content to html using v-html, but files contains full html page (w/ scripts), and nuxt throw and error in this case, 'cos v-html don't allow using js (or maybe another reasons, which I can't understand)

How can I make dynamic proxy for this in NuxtJS?

Comment: First off, why do you want this kind of behavior? What are those HTML pages exactly? Also, where do you host your app? Could use some Netlify redirects for that purpose I guess. Do you use your app as SSG or SSR too?

Comment: @kissu HTML-pages exported from site constructor (about 200 pages, some of them updating few times per day) through API. App is hosted on simple nginx server, using SSR. Want this behavior because want to automate process of exporting pages from constructor service

Comment: If you have it as SSR, then you will not need to generate all the pages each time, accessing a dynamic route will be enough, then letting your Node server serving the adequate page. No need for a proxy even. As for the constructor, I recommend using a Headless CMS if you want to allow somebody to do so. `.html` pages seems quite unflexible to me. Luckily, all the Headless CMS have a webhook integration that will update the API and allow you to have the content available straight away. There are quite some integrations + niceties especially for non-tech people too!

Comment: @kissu unfortunately, we can't just move from existing external page constructor to headless CMS. I need to deal with things that I described in original post

Comment: I was mainly recommending that way because using `v-html` + custom scripts is not the way to go (huge security breach for example!). And that the whole process would need quite some improvements, hence my suggestion. Still, even if you don't want to use a Headless CMS, the rest of my comment is still relevant. You mainly need to have a mapper between your URL and the HTML file you want to reach.

Comment: @kissu can you please tell me a bit more about mapper? Can't understand, how could it be done

Comment: It's a fancy word to say that if you go to `/bar`, it needs to be the given `page2.html`. Mainly an object with a key/value pair, checking the URL path and giving you the HTML you wish. Can be done directly into a `[builder].vue` dynamic page, nothing more complex needed.

Comment: I've done something like this, but how can I get html-content in vue component and render it without nuxt's wrappers (without using v-html)?

Comment: I'd say you can't and also, why would you do such thing in the first place? It doesn't work that way (of course it depends on the scripts you're using there, but you already know that it's a bad way of doing things)? Nuxt is probably not the right tool if you want to display HTML only. I had a client who wanted this kind of flexibility: like using jQuery, importing 3rd party libs, using Vue's state etc...but it's risky, bad and not optimal at all so you should just say no. :) A lot of issues will come, the performance may be quite bad too, use regular good practices even if it needs refacto.

Comment: So
We've got an nuxt application, that has a lot of pages, and now we also need to serve some static html pages (that are continuously updating), exported from external service, and I try to understand, how I can solve this task.
You said that it can be done directly in a `[builder].vue`, but I can't understand, how, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone looking for answer for same question

Solve this by creating simple server middleware

in /pages_proxy/index.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const { Router } = require('express');
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
const router = Router()

router.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  const pages = { '/foo/': 'page1.html', '/bar/': 'page2.html', ... }
  const page = pages[req.path];

  if (page) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../static/pages', page));
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

app.use(router)

module.exports = app
```

in nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: {
  '/': '~/pages_proxy'
},
```